# CutyCapt make is failing

Tags: build, 64-bit, png, capture, ubuntu-10.04

I'm having trouble installing CutyCapt on Ubuntu server 10.04.2 AMD64 - headless.  I have all the latest qt3 & qt4 installed, G++, subversion, and xvfb.

I do the following:

```
sudo svn co https://cutycapt.svn.sourceforge.net/svnroot/cutycapt

A    cutycapt/CutyCapt
A    cutycapt/CutyCapt/CutyCapt.hpp
A    cutycapt/CutyCapt/CutyCapt.pro
A    cutycapt/CutyCapt/CutyCapt.cpp

Checked out revision 6.

mike@server 12:40:09 ubu /usr/lib

$ cd cutycapt/

mike@server 12:40:14 ubu /usr/lib/cutycapt

$ cd CutyCapt/

mike@server 12:40:17 ubu /usr/lib/cutycapt/CutyCapt

$ ls

CutyCapt.cpp  CutyCapt.hpp  CutyCapt.pro

mike@server 12:40:18 ubu /usr/lib/cutycapt/CutyCapt

$ sudo qmake

mike@server 12:40:25 ubu /usr/lib/cutycapt/CutyCapt

$ sudo make
```

And I keep getting the following.....

```
g++ -c -pipe -g -Wall -W -O2 -D_REENTRANT  -DQT_NO_DEBUG -DQT_THREAD_SUPPORT -DQT_SHARED -DQT_TABLET_SUPPORT -I/usr/share/qt3/mkspecs/default -I. -I../../../include/qt3 -o 
CutyCapt.o CutyCapt.cpp

CutyCapt.cpp:21:24: error: QApplication: No such file or directory
CutyCapt.cpp:22:20: error: QtWebKit: No such file or directory
CutyCapt.cpp:23:17: error: QtGui: No such file or directory
CutyCapt.cpp:24:25: error: QSvgGenerator: No such file or directory
CutyCapt.cpp:25:20: error: QPrinter: No such file or directory
CutyCapt.cpp:26:18: error: QTimer: No such file or directory
CutyCapt.cpp:27:22: error: QByteArray: No such file or directory
CutyCapt.cpp:28:27: error: QNetworkRequest: No such file or directory

In file included from CutyCapt.cpp:29:
CutyCapt.hpp:4: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:5: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Q_OBJECT’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:7: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘public’
CutyCapt.hpp:9: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QString’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:9: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:10: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QString’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:10: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:13: error: ‘QString’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.hpp:16: error: ‘QString’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.hpp:17: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QString’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:17: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:18: error: ‘QWebFrame’ has not been declared
CutyCapt.hpp:18: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QString’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:18: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:19: error: ‘QWebFrame’ has not been declared
CutyCapt.hpp:19: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QString’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:19: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:20: error: ‘QWebFrame’ has not been declared
CutyCapt.hpp:20: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QString’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:20: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:21: error: ‘QString’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.hpp:22: error: ‘QString’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.hpp:23: error: ‘QString’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.hpp:28: error: expected class-name before ‘{’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:29: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘Q_OBJECT’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:31: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘public’
CutyCapt.hpp:39: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QString’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:39: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:45: error: expected ‘:’ before ‘slots’
CutyCapt.hpp:46: error: expected primary-expression before ‘void’
CutyCapt.hpp:46: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘slots’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:46: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘void’
CutyCapt.hpp:59: error: ‘QString’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.hpp:62: error: ‘OutputFormat’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.hpp:63: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QObject’ with no type
CutyCapt.hpp:63: error: expected ‘;’ before ‘*’ token
CutyCapt.hpp:64: error: ‘QString’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.hpp:65: error: ‘QString’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.cpp:45: error: ‘OutputFormat’ in class ‘CutyCapt’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.cpp:49: error: ‘SvgFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:50: error: ‘PdfFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:51: error: ‘PsFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:52: error: ‘InnerTextFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:53: error: ‘HtmlFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:54: error: ‘RenderTreeFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:55: error: ‘JpegFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:56: error: ‘PngFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:57: error: ‘MngFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:58: error: ‘TiffFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:59: error: ‘GifFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:60: error: ‘BmpFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:61: error: ‘PpmFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:62: error: ‘XbmFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:63: error: ‘XpmFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:64: error: ‘OtherFormat’ is not a member of ‘CutyCapt’
CutyCapt.cpp:67: error: ‘QString’ does not name a type
CutyCapt.cpp:73: error: ‘bool CutyPage::javaScriptConfirm’ is not a static member of ‘class CutyPage’
CutyCapt.cpp:73: error: ‘QWebFrame’ was not declared in this scope
CutyCapt.cpp:73: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
CutyCapt.cpp:73: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
CutyCapt.cpp:73: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
CutyCapt.cpp:73: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
CutyCapt.cpp:78: error: ‘bool CutyPage::javaScriptPrompt’ is not a static member of ‘class CutyPage’
CutyCapt.cpp:78: error: ‘QWebFrame’ was not declared in this scope
CutyCapt.cpp:78: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
CutyCapt.cpp:79: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
CutyCapt.cpp:80: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’
CutyCapt.cpp:81: error: ‘QString’ was not declared in this scope
CutyCapt.cpp:81: error: expected primary-expression before ‘)’ token
CutyCapt.cpp:81: error: initializer expression list treated as compound expression
CutyCapt.cpp:81: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘;’ before ‘{’ token
CutyCapt.cpp:86: error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of ‘QString’ with no type
CutyCapt.cpp:86: error: expected ‘,’ or ‘...’ before ‘&’ token
CutyCapt.cpp:86: warning: unused parameter ‘QString’
CutyCapt.cpp:93: error: variable or field ‘javaScriptAlert’ declared void
CutyCapt.cpp:93: error: ‘QWebFrame’ was not declared in this scope
CutyCapt.cpp:93: error: expected primary-expression before ‘,’ token
CutyCapt.cpp:93: error: expected primary-expression before ‘const’

make: *** [CutyCapt.o] Error 1
```

Is there some environment variable that needs changing, or something to modify in the Makefile ?

Comment: Ever come right with this? I'm having the same problem now...

Answer (score -2):

http://cutycapt.sourceforge.net/

```
cd /usr/local/CutyCapt

/usr/bin/qmake-qt4

make
```